# validation enable/disable on class properties

Tags: c#, .net, oop

Sorry for the title, don't know what should I use for this issue.

Issue is I am using Attributes & reflection for validation implementation in my C# application something like this.

```
public class foo : validationBase
{
    [RequiredAttribute("id is required")]
    public int id { get; set; }
    [RequiredAttribute("name is required")]
    public string name { get; set; }

    void save()
    {
       this.IsValid();
       //some code
    }
    void update()
    {
       this.IsValid();
       //some code
    }
    void delete()
    {
       // Need some magic here to ignore name attribute's required validation as only id 
       // is needed for delete operation
       this.IsValid();

       //some code
    }
}
```

as you may see in delete operation I don't want to validate `name` property's required validation, **NOTE there may be some more validation attributes to a single property and there could be a requirement that one attribute's validation should not fire but other's should**.

Please provide you views to solve this one.

Answer (score 0):

Use a flag-able enum and, pass it and check it in `IsValid()`. If an opeation requires to be validaed, then verify it. Somthing like this:

```
    public sealed class RequiredAttributeAttribute : Attribute
    {
        private Operation _Operations = Operation.Insert | Operation.Update;
        public Operation Operations
        {
            get { return this._Operations; }
            set { this._Operations = value; }
        }

        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    }

    [Flags]
    public enum Operation
    {
        Insert = 2,
        Update = 4,
        Delete = 6
    }
```

then validate the props like this:

```
        void delete()
        {
            this.IsValid(Operation.Delete);
        }


        public bool IsValid(Operation operation)
        {
            //...
        }
```

Comment: insert, update, delete are common methods but in a large scale application classes may/will have lots of methods, So I don't think we can define operation enum like that. And one more thing to keep in mind is IsValid is a global method it just pick property checks what kind of validation to check for & validate it that's it nothing else & this method should not know any more than that otherwise this method won't be a global one, I'll have to write a different IsValid for every class I don't want to do that.